# Connecting DynamoDB Local with AWScala gives a SocketTimeoutException

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I am trying to run DynamoDB on my computer.I downloaded the DynamoDB and run it.

[image: output from running the DynamoDB local JAR]

After that i tried to connect database with https://github.com/seratch/AWScala

```
 implicit val dynamoDB = DynamoDB.local()
 dynamoDB.createTable(
  name = "Dummy",
  hashPK = "Id" -> AttributeType.String
 )
 println(dynamoDB.listTables().getTableNames)
```

Also

- Jdk version is: jdk1.8.0_66
- Scala sdk version is: 2.11.7
- AWScala version is: 0.5.5
- I am using IntelliJIdea 15.0.1

And it gives an error like this:

```
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient executeHelper
INFO: Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at com.amazonaws.http.protocol.SdkHttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(SdkHttpRequestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:769)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:506)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:318)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1803)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.createTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:832)
    at awscala.dynamodbv2.DynamoDB$class.createTable(DynamoDB.scala:109)
    at awscala.dynamodbv2.DynamoDBClient.createTable(DynamoDB.scala:348)
    at awscala.dynamodbv2.DynamoDB$class.create(DynamoDB.scala:84)
    at awscala.dynamodbv2.DynamoDBClient.create(DynamoDB.scala:348)
    at awscala.dynamodbv2.DynamoDB$class.createTable(DynamoDB.scala:58)
    at awscala.dynamodbv2.DynamoDBClient.createTable(DynamoDB.scala:348)
    at tr.com.cma.agent.tagger.DynamoController$Test$$anonfun$2.apply$mcV$sp(DynamoController$Test.scala:24)
    at tr.com.cma.agent.tagger.DynamoController$Test$$anonfun$2.apply(DynamoController$Test.scala:19)
    at tr.com.cma.agent.tagger.DynamoController$Test$$anonfun$2.apply(DynamoController$Test.scala:19)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$class.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1647)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.withFixture(Suite.scala:1122)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.withFixture(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1644)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1656)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1656)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:306)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTest(FlatSpecLike.scala:1656)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTest(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1714)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1714)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:413)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:390)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:427)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:401)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:396)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:483)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTests(FlatSpecLike.scala:1714)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTests(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
    at org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1424)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.org$scalatest$FlatSpecLike$$super$run(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1760)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1760)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:545)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.run(FlatSpecLike.scala:1760)
    at org.scalatest.FlatSpec.run(FlatSpec.scala:1683)
    at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:55)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2563)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$3.apply(Runner.scala:2557)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:2557)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1044)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1043)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:2722)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1043)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:883)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

How can i solve this problem?

Thank you!